# Pandas df to MySQL gives the same timestamp

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am trying to upload a CSV to MySQL by first reading the CSV using pandas's .read_csv function and then using the .to_sql function to upload it to the db table.

I have a modification_time column defined in the table schema as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY unique_id (id),
  modification_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  insertion_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

and the code to read and upload the data is as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector
from urllib.parse import quote  

conn = mysql.connector.connect(
host='xx.x.x.xx', user='username', password='password', database='dbname')
sql = 'TRUNCATE ' + 'test_table' + ";"
cur = conn.cursor()
conn.commit()
conn.close()

engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://username:%s@xx.x.x.xx/dbname' % quote('password'),echo=True)
df = pd.read_csv("inputdata.csv")
df.to_sql('test_table', con = engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

The data is being uploaded fine for all the columns except the modification_time and insertion_time columns. The same timestamp is repeated for all the records in the table.

*I want the different insertion timestamps for each row as they are getting uploaded one after another (I am passing ***None*** in the method parameter in the .to_sql function)*

[The method parameter is referred from here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#io-sql-method)

Any suggestions are very much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: I don't see a problem with that, you have told it to input current time.So it reads the current time and that's what is input. What did you expect?

Comment: I want separate timestamps for each record, even a millisecond of difference is required. Like when one record is uploaded then only the second one would be uploaded right?

Answer (score 1):

The default MySQL TIMESTAMP records times with a granularity of seconds, so it's quite likely that multiple records will be inserted in the same second.

```sql
MariaDB [test]> create table tstest (
    -> name varchar(4),
    -> ts timestamp default current_timestamp(6)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.274 sec)

MariaDB [test]> insert into tstest (name) values ('a');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.057 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select * from tstest;
+------+---------------------+
| name | ts                  |
+------+---------------------+
| a    | 2021-12-28 09:42:26 |
+------+---------------------+
```

You can specify a [fractional seconds](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fractional-seconds.html) value in the column description to increase the granularity of the timestamps recorded (6 is the highest value accepted in MySQL 8.0):

```sql
MariaDB [test]> create table tstest ( name varchar(4), ts timestamp(6) default current_timestamp() );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.247 sec)

MariaDB [test]> insert into tstest (name) values ('a');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.040 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select * from tstest;
+------+----------------------------+
| name | ts                         |
+------+----------------------------+
| a    | 2021-12-28 09:47:10.708227 |
+------+----------------------------+
```

This doesn't guarantee that you won't have collisions (and may be subject to the precision of the system clock), but it should make them more unlikely.

While this approach may help, if you want timestamps based on the order of records in your dataframe then I would consider setting them on arrival in the dataframe; relying on the SQL engine processing the records in a specific order may not be safe or portable.